# Power automate. Multiple rows in one approval

Tags: power-automate

I am working on a approval flow. I have 2 SQL tables like this for example:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nN5F.png)

I have a trigger "When a new item is created" in sql. Trigger is for table TABLE1.

And I get rows from second table, with filter: Table1.ID=Table2.ItemID
My flow looks like this:

[Power automate 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgM81.png)

[Power automate 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJtw.png)

I get 2 seperate approval requests to email. Instead of all data in one request. Because there are 2 rows filtered in Get Rows(V2) 2. How would I get these 2 rows(or more) included in only one Approval request?

Comment: Do not add "solved" or similar language to your question's title, nor post solutions to the question in the question itself. If you have a solution to your question, post an _answer_ and accept it. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I have solved this issue in this post: [Approvals, get data from 2 tables](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Approvals-get-data-from-2-tables/m-p/876038#M68066)